# Place content under iOS UITabBar

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller, ios9, uitabbar

I'm trying to place my content under UITabBar. I created a Storyboard with controller in it and attached UIView to the bottom of content view of that controller(with constraints). After that, i created another Storyboard with UITabBarController and linked one of the tabs to the first Storyboard by storyboard reference. And the problem is that my UIView appearing always above the UITabBar while i want it to be under tab bar. Is there any way to achieve my goal?

[Storyboard with UITabBarController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYzRb.png)

[Storyboard with my view attached to the bottom of the content view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UOZX.png)

Comment: Elaborate your question with screenshots and code that you have done/tried

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far?

Comment: @BangOperator
Sorry, as new user i can't attach more than two images. I updated my post with screenshots of storyboards

Comment: Why are you using two storyboards? You should use one story board with multiple view controllers

Answer (score 0):

For using tabbarcontroller you should follow below scenario :

Drag tabbarcontroller to canvas (interfacebuilder), it will comes with two default view controllers. That means initially you have two tabs.

If you want more tab the drag another view controller to interface builder and then from tabbarviewcontroller `ctrl + drag to that new View controller` and from popup select `relationship segue (viewController)`.

By this way you will able to new tab in tabbarcontroller and view in you tabs will not cover tabbar.

Comment: The problem is not that content of my view covering tabbar. I'm trying to place my view under tabbar

Comment: I have show your updated question with screenshot.
Why are you using two storyboards? You should use one story board with multiple view controllers